# JavaScript Loops: for...in vs for

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, for-in-loop

I faced a strange behaviour in Javascript. I get

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

exception for the `removeAttribute` function in the following code:

```
var buttons = controlDiv.getElementsByTagName("button");
for ( var button in buttons )
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

When I change the code with the following, the problem disappears:

```
var buttons = controlDiv.getElementsByTagName("button");
for ( var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++ )
    buttons[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
```

What is the value of `button` inside the `for...in`?

Comment: Try it: `for ( var button in buttons ) alert( button );` so you can see what `for` .. `in` sets `button` to.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Don't use `for..in` for Array iteration.

It's important to understand that Javascript Array's square bracket syntax (`[]`) for accessing indicies is actually inherited from the `Object`...

```
obj.prop === obj['prop']  // true
```

The `for..in` structure does not work like a more traditional `for..each/in` that would be found in other languages (php, python, etc...).

Javascript's `for..in` is designed to iterate over the properties of an **object**.  Producing the **key** of each property.  Using this **key** combined with the `Object`'s bracket syntax, you can easily access the values you are after.

```
var obj = {
    foo: "bar",
    fizz: "buzz",
    moo: "muck"
};

for ( var prop in obj ) {
    console.log(prop);      // foo / fizz / moo
    console.log(obj[prop]); // bar / buzz / muck
}
```

And because the Array is simply an Object with **sequential numeric property names (indexes)** the `for..in` works in a similar way, producing the numeric indicies just as it produces the property names above.

An important characteristic of the `for..in` structure is that it continues to search for enumerable properties up the prototype chain.  It will also iterate **inherited enumerable properties**.  It is up to you to verify that the current property exists directly on the local object and not the prototype it is attached to with `hasOwnProperty()`...

```
for ( var prop in obj ) {
    if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
        // prop is actually obj's property (not inherited)
    }
}
```

([More on Prototypal Inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html))

The problem with using the `for..in` structure on the Array type is that there is no garauntee as to what order the properties are produced...  and generally speaking that is a farily important feature in processing an array.

Another problem is that it usually [slower than](http://jsperf.com/for-in-or-for/10) a standard `for` implementation.

### Bottom Line

Using a `for...in` to iterate arrays is like using the butt of a screw driver to drive a nail...  why wouldn't you just use a hammer (`for`)?

Comment: This is correct, but there's another reason to avoid using `for ... in` for arrays. [From MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in): _...the for...in statement will return the name of your user-defined properties in addition to the numeric indexes. ..._

Comment: for..in structure is that it continues to search for enumerable properties up the prototype chain. It will also iterate inherited enumerable properties....i am a little vague about this part,can you please explain it

Comment: The "speed test" is fatally flawed. The Object has no length property, so the for loop is going from 0 to *undefined* (i.e. it doesn't even enter the loop).

Answer (score 7):

`for...in` is to be used when you want to loop over the properties of an object. But it works the same as a normal `for` loop: The loop variable contains the current "index", meaning the property of the object and not the value.

To iterate over arrays, you should use a normal `for` loop. `buttons` is not an array but a `NodeList` (an array like structure).

If iterate over `buttons` with `for...in` with:

```
for(var i in a) {
    console.log(i)
}
```

You will see that it output something like:

```
1
2
...
length
item
```

because `length` and `item` are two properties of an object of type `NodeList`. So if you'd naively use `for..in`, you would try to access `buttons['length'].removeAttribute()` which will throw an error as `buttons['length']` is a function and not a DOM element.

So the correct way is to use a normal `for` loop. But there is another issue:

`NodeList`s are live, meaning whenever you access e.g. `length`, the list is updated (the elements are searched again). Therefore you should avoid unnecessary calls to `length`.

Example:

```
for(var i = 0, l = buttons.length; i < l, i++)
```

Comment: For avoiding calls to length, I prefer `for (var i = 0; i in buttons; i++)`.  I like how explicit this check is, rather than implicitly checking against the length.

Comment: @gilly3: Actually I prefer `for(var i = buttons.length; i--; )` but sometimes the order is important. And I could imagine that `i in buttons` still reevaluates the list (besides that it is probably slower than a number comparison).

Answer (score 0):

`for(var key in obj) {  }` iterates over all elements in the object, including those of its prototypes.
So if you are using it and cannot know nothing extended `Object.prototype` you should always test `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` and skip the key if this check returns false.

`for(start; continuation; loop)` is a C-style loop: `start` is executed before the loop, `continuation` is tested and the loop only continues while it's true, `loop` is executed after every loop.

Answer (score 0):

While for..in should not generally be used for Arrays, however prior to ES5 there was a case for using it with sparse arrays.

As noted in other answers, the primary issues with for..in and Arrays are:

1. The properties are not necessarily returned in order (i.e. not 0, 1, 2 etc.)
2. All enumerable properties are returned, including the non–index properties and those on the `[[Prototype]]` chain. This leads to lower performance as a *hasOwnProperty* test is probably required to avoid inherited properties.

One reason to use for..in prior to ES5 was to improve performance with sparse arrays, provided order doesn't matter. For example, in the following:

```
var a = [0];
a[1000] = 1;
```

Iterating over *a* using for..in will be much faster than using a for loop, as it will only visit two properties whereas a for loop will try 1001.

However, this case is made redundant by ES5's *forEach*, which only visits members that exist, so:

```
a.forEach();
```

will also only iterate over two properties, in order.