# for(var i in aArray) VS for(i=0; i<aArray.length; i++)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I just want to ask if the **in_array_orig** and  **in_array_new** is just the same.
and also im confused on the result when comparing both array (**aArr1** vs **aArr2**).

can someone explain me. thanks

Here is my sample test code

```
function echo(s)
{
    document.write(s);
}

function in_array_orig(oItem, aArray)
{   
    for (var i=0; i<aArray.length; i++) if (aArray[i] == oItem) return true;

    return false;
}

function in_array_new(oItem, aArray)
{
    for (var i in aArray) if (aArray[i] == oItem) return true;

    return false;
}

var a = ['gab', '24', 'manila'];

var aArr1 = [1];
var b = {0:aArr1, 1:24, 2:'manila'};

var aArr2 = [1];


echo(in_array_orig(24, a)); // true
echo(in_array_new(24, b)); // true

echo(in_array_orig(aArr2, b)); // false
echo(in_array_new(aArr2, b)); // false

echo ((aArr1==aArr2)); // false
echo ((aArr1===aArr2)); // false
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What language are you using? JavaScript? Add it as tag please.

Comment: opps, sorry about that. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `in` operator returns true if the property is in the object. This includes a lookup right up through the prototype chain. For example:

```
Object.prototype.k = 5;
f = {};
'k' in f; // true
```

Even though `f` is an empty object, it's prototype (as all types in JS) includes that of `Object`, which has the property `'k'`.

Although you didn't ask, a useful function here to check the object's own properties only, is `.hasOwnProperty()`, so in our example above:

```
f.hasOwnProperty('k'); // false, that's more what we would expect
```

Although for arrays you don't (usually) want to iterate over all properties, since these properties may include things other than index values, so both for reasons of performance and expected behaviour, a regular `for(var i=0;i<n;i++)` should be used.

As such, if you're using arrays go with `in_array_orig`, and for objects where you are interested in their properties, use `in_array_new` (which should be renamed appropriately, `in_obj` or something).

In addition, `[1] == [1]` returns false since the two objects/arrays are not the *same* object. Indeed each of their properties and indexes have the same value, although they aren't sitting at the same place in memory, and thus are not considered equal. You can easily build ([or find on the net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)) a deep search `equals()` routine to check whether two objects/arrays are indeed equal *in value* (as opposed to address).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is already discussed here in SO.

See it here

- [JavaScript: Difference between for..in and for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-difference-between-for-in-and-for)
- [JavaScript foreach Vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-foreach-vs-for)

Comment: hello thanks for the link. i cant find those links on my search keys so i just decided to post a question.

Comment: That's OK the importance is, you now understand its differences.

Answer (score 0):

`in_array_orig` will work only with arrays, `in_array_new` will also work with dictionaries. For arrays, their results will be the same, but there's no guarantee that items will be processed in correct order in `in_array_new` (in case of this function it doesn't matter).

About array comparison, it seems that JavaScript doesn't compare arrays element-by-element, but rather compares if the array is the same object in memory, e.g.:

```
aArr1 == aArr1 // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are differences between the two.

Firstly, the syntax `for(var i=0; i<aArray.length; i++)` will obviously only work correctly for arrays which only have numeric keys, and where there aren't any gaps in the key sequence. If that doesn't apply to your data, then this syntax will obviously give you problems.

But the real differences come down to how Javascript treats arrays and objects.

Using `for(x in y)` causes JS to loop through all properties and methods in an **object**.

In JS, an *array* is simply a type of *object*, with a few pre-defined methods and properties, such as `length` to find the number of array elements, `pop()` and `push()` to add and remove elements, etc.

If you use the `for(x in y)` syntax on an *array*, it will include some of these methods and properties in the loop. This is unlikely to be what you intended, and could cause some odd side effects.

Therefore, if you want to use `for(x in y)`, you are better off starting with an *object* rather than an *array*.

I hope that helps.

Comment: nice. thank you very much for this info. actually we have a util class that has in_array so im confused if my updated in_array that can also handle objects is just the same as the old.

Comment: -1 no it does not include pop & push. These have their enumerable property set to false.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, pls refer http://www.openjs.com/articles/for_loop.php

About the second:

```
echo(in_array_orig(24, a)); // true
echo(in_array_new(24, b)); // true
```

I think this won't be a problem to you.

```
echo(in_array_orig(aArr2, b));
echo(in_array_new(aArr2, b));
```

Both of these would definitely be false, becuz they are no where inside b. If you make a small change in b:

```
var b = {0:aArr1, 1:24, 2:'manila', 3:[1]};
```

then try this:

```
console.log(in_array_new(aArr2, b[3]));
console.log(in_array_orig(aArr2, b[3]));
```

they are both **True** now.

Finally, the last:

```
echo ((aArr1==aArr2));
```

"==" operator compares their value, so this is false because they clearly bears different content, meaning value.

```
echo ((aArr1===aArr2));
```

"===" compares their value and type, their values are different but their types are the same, you can check it by:

```
console.log(typeof aArr1===typeof aArr2);
```

thus it is still a **False**.

Answer (score -1):

> if the in_array_orig and in_array_new is just the same

Yes, they are. (same behavior)

> im confused on the result when comparing both array (aArr1 vs aArr2)

We can't compare array like this: `aArr1 == aArr2`

Comment: -1 What about extending Array.prototype? There not the same behaviour

Comment: I mean `in_array_orig` and `in_array_new` return same result

Comment: They dont. See @davin 's answer.

Comment: Visible result is same for both.

Comment: `Array.prototype.foo = 4; in_array_orig(4, []); in_array_new(4, []);` They are not the same.

Comment: Where u see `Array.prototype.foo = 4;` in ilovekhym's code? My answer is related to posted code. Generally you are right, I don't negate.

Comment: @atlavis He might have Prototype loaded or MooTools loaded. Any of _n_ random javascript libraries he has loaded can alter the prototype.