# javascript for…in + if-test (inside of a switch inside of a form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, for-loop, switch-statement

I have a question in a form asking if you've used alcohol, drugs, both, neither, "777", "999".

> alcohol : question 2; drugs : question 3; both : questions 2 + 3; neither or "777" or "999" : question 4.

I have a jquery change() listen setup (and is working), and I have a switch statement setup and is mostly working, except for `neither||"777"||"999"`. Inside `case "neither…"` I have an array `vices` and a `for…in` loop. My assumption is that `for…in` functions like/similarly to php's `foreach`.

I need to detect if the question is **not** already `inactive` before I hide it and set its value to *not applicable* (so I know it was purposeful rather than leaving it empty).

```
case "neither" || "777" || "999":
    var vices = new Array('alcohol','drugs');
    for ( vice in vices ) {
        if ( $("ul#vice").hasClass("inactive") == false ) {
            $("ul#vice").append('<input name="'+vice+'" type="radio" value="not applicable" checked="checked" />');
            $("ul#vice").delay(250).queue( function() {$(this).addClass("inactive");queue()} );
        }
    }
```

I think the problem has something to do with the `$("ul#vice")`, but I'm not sure. (I've tried `$("ul#"+vice)`, but that didn't work either).

A question stuff looks like:

```
.inactive{display:none; z-index:-5}
```

#

```
<ul id="alcohol" class="inactive">How many alcoholic drinks do you have?
    <li><input name="alcohol" type="text" maxlength="2" /><span id="alcohol" class="inactive"></span></li>
    <li><input name="alcohol" type="radio" value="777" />Don't know</li>
    <li><input name="alcohol" type="radio" value="999" />Prefer to not answer</li>
    <input name="alcohol" type="radio" value="not applicable" checked="checked" />
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, a quick search would tell you how `for...in` actually does work: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a quick search would tell you how for...in actually does work: http://w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp

You need:

```
for (i=0; i<vices.length; i++) { 
    var vice = vices[i]; ...
}
```

And since that is a variable, `$("ul#" + vice)` is in fact correct.

Comment: yes! that worked. (I don't like this structure of a for loop—I much prefer php's `foreach`) Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

you are incorrect on your assumption that `for...in` is similar to `foreach`...

my previous answer.
[JavaScript Loops: for...in vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-difference-between-for-in-and-for/5263872#5263872)

Comment: So `for…in` returns a number, like 3 if it is the 3rd object in the array? (seems all but useless). Thanks for the info!

Comment: it's just a shortened sytax, but as I pointed out, it generally better for multiple reason's to use a regular `for`