# difference between for..in and for loops, and counter declaration

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, for-loop

the difference (speed, performace, side effects, ...) between implementations of the **`for`** loop:

between

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < length; i++){ //Do something}
// more code
```

and

```
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){ //Do something}
// more code
```

and

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++){ //Do something}
// more code
```

and between

```
var e;
for( e in array){ //Do something}
// more code
```

and

```
for(var e in array){ //Do something}
// more code
```

and

```
for(e in array){ //Do something}
// more code
```

Comment: this has to have been asked a million times....

Comment: doubt they are vary in performance, but I might be wrong

Comment: Can the array be modified within the loop? Do you actually access the array elements in the first two examples (is there even an array)?

Comment: @mu: no. The other question is about Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Loops: for...in vs for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-loops-for-in-vs-for)

Comment: @rkmax - Don't change your question after people have answered. Your change made my existing answer wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.

JavaScript variables have only function scope, and although you can place a `var` statement in the initialisation part of a `for` loop in reality the declaration is "[hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)" to the top of the scope such that when your second case examples run they're treated exactly like the first cases.

**EDIT:** Since you updated the question *after* I answered, the third syntax that you added where you don't use the `var` keyword means the variable `i` (or `e`) will be created as a global - unless it already exists as a global in which case the existing variable will be overwritten. Global variable access is slower than local variable access.

NOTE: my interpretation of the question is that it is not comparing a standard for loop with the for..in variant, it is just compared the different variable declaration methods with each other for a standard for loop, then doing the same again for a for..in loop.

Comment: Well, you are right that it doesn't really matter where one places the `var`, other than wasting bytes of code. BUT, the for...in, is not the same as the other for loop, there's situations in which one will work better than the other...PS: I didn't downvote...I swear XD (really)

Comment: That answers half of the question (does not deserve a downvote, though)

Comment: @JCOC611 - The question doesn't compare a standard for loop with a for..in, it compares different standard for loops with each other, and then (kind of in parallel) it compares different for..in loops with each other. Also the question was edited _after_ I posted my answer to introduce a third syntax not originally mentioned. So to whoever downvoted (especially without an explantion): that was pretty harsh.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Ah I missed that...sorry. +1 :)

Comment: @JCOC611 - well, maybe the way I read the question wasn't how it was actually intended but in any case thanks for balancing up the downvote with your +1.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in relation to the declariation of your counter variable..

***BUT ALWAYS DECLARE YOUR VARIABLES WITH*** `var`

Otherwise they pollute javascript's already dirty global scope...

As far as `for...in` vs traditional `for` **[look here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-loops-for-in-vs-for/5263872#5263872)**

(*Which is my answer to the duplicate question...*)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference between for loop and for/in loop in javascript. Here is what is different

consider this array

```
var myArr = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

Later, I add an element to this array, but in a different way, like so:

```
myArr[myArr.length + 1] = "d";
```

At this point of time, this is what the array looks like, if you console.log it

```
["c", "b", "a", undefined × 1, "d"]
```

Now, let us loop through the array using for and for/in loop and see what the difference is:
first, lets try the for loop

```
for(var i = 0; i != myArr.length; i++) {     // note, i used " != " instead of " < ". Yes this is faster.
  console.log(myArr[i]);
}
// output will look like this:
// "a" 
// "b" 
// "c"
// undefined × 1
// "d" 
// - This still shows the undefined value in the array.
```

Now, lets look at the for/in loop

```
for(key in myArr) {
  console.log(myArr[key]);
}
// array will look like:
// "a"
// "b"
// "c"
// "d"
// This will skip the undefined value.
```

**Difference 1**: The javascript interpreter will skip all values that are null or undefined when using the for/in loop. Also, the for/in loop will convert all values if it encounters a primitive value, to its equivalent wrapper object. Where as the for loop doesn't do this.

**Difference 2**: When using the for loop, we declared the variable i within the loop, this variable will be scoped within a function, if the for loop is written within that function. Which means, until the function ends, the variable i is still available, even outside of the for loop, but within that function. Where as, in case of the for/in loop, the scope of the "key" variable dies immediately after the for/in loop stops executing, which means, there is less memory utilization.