# Accessing sub-objects in a "for in" loop?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Here is some sample code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
pingpong = {
    paddleA: {
        speed: 5,
    },
    paddleB: {
        speed: 6,
    },
    paddleAI: {
        AI1: "paddleA",
        AI2: "paddleB"
    }
}

paddleAI = pingpong.paddleAI;
paddleA = pingpong.paddleA;
paddleB = pingpong.paddleB;

for (paddle in paddleAI) {
    document.write(paddleAI[paddle].speed);
}
```

When I run this code, it returns "undefined"

I am trying to use the text values in `paddleAI` as which paddle's speed I want to access.

How would I get that code to return the speed values of `paddleA` and `paddleB`?

**Note:**
This is only demonstration resembling my actual code, therefore I don't have much room to dramatically restructure how I am storing and accessing my values.

Comment: This would work, except you're referencing `paddleAI` instead of `pingpong`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to fix that in the sample code. I know that is not the issue now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you are after...

Using the contents of `pingpong.paddleAI` to tell you what paddles are available...

Your problem is that you were using `paddle` in the loop expecting the paddle name, when in fact you were getting the property name ( ex... `AI1`)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263872/555384

```
for (paddle in paddleAI) {
    document.write(pingpong[paddleAI[paddle]].speed);
}
```

Although this seems like **really bad** way to do it...

Also, your trailing commas will make IE throw fits... remove the last comma in a object/array literal declaration

Comment: I tried it and it works. I don't know why exactly it works this way, but I guess not everything has to make sense. Thanks for the answer!

BTW I removed the trailing commas from my example. I don't have them in my full code, so I'm not sure why I put them there xD

Comment: Read up on `for..in` to understand how it works... http://stackoverflow.com/a/5263872/555384

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xa9AK/)

You want to loop through the keys of `pingpong.paddleAI`, not just `paddleAI`.  Also, you want to grab the **value** of the `paddleAI` property, not the key

```
for (paddle in pingpong.paddleAI) {
    var keyVal = pingpong.paddleAI[paddle]; 
    if (pingpong[keyVal].speed)
        console.log(pingpong[keyVal].speed);
    else  //if you want
        console.log("no speed on " + keyVal);
}
```

Comment: @ryansworld10 - does this code no accomplish what you're after?  Not sure why this was downvoted.

Comment: I removed the downvote. It just seemed a bit different than what I was looking for at first.

Comment: @ryansworld10 - thanks - it's the same as all the other upvoted answers, it's just broken out a bit more

Answer (score 1):

Think what you're after is this:

```
pingpong = {
    paddleA: {
        speed: 5,
    },
    paddleB: {
        speed: 6,
    },
    paddleAI: {
        AI1: "paddleA",
        AI2: "paddleB",
    },
}

for (paddle in pingpong.paddleAI) {
    document.write(pingpong[pingpong.paddleAI[paddle]].speed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your initial reference was off. Also, paddle would refer to the object, but you need the value (which is really a key). Code speaks louder than words: [(jsFiddle demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/26F3X/)

```
var pingpong = {
    paddleA: {
        speed: 5,
    },
    paddleB: {
        speed: 6,
    },
    paddleAI: {
        AI1: "paddleA",
        AI2: "paddleB",
    },
}
//reference paddleAI
var pAI = pingpong.paddleAI;
for (paddle in pAI) {
    //here paddle reference AI1 or AI2 but we want its value
    var key = pAI[paddle];
    //and on top of that its value is a reference to the key we really want
    var paddleRef = pingpong[key];
    document.write(paddleRef.speed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(pingpong.paddleA.speed)
alert(pingpong.paddleb.speed)
```

It's a simple hierarchy, no loops required.

Comment: As I said this is a demonstration based off my code. I know I can simply show the values, but that won't work for what I am trying to accomplish in my application.