# why does JS for each in function give too many?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, for-in-loop

This has bothered me for a while, see my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DHR8Q/, which contains the following javascript code:

```
var id = "11111;22222;33333";

id = id.split(";");

alert(typeof id);

for (var i in id){
    alert(id[i]);
}​
```

When I split the variable `id` by the character ";", then I use the for loop, I would assume that `i == 0,1,2` because the string `id` was split into 3 parts, but this is not what happens.  In reality `i == 0,1,2,3,4...`.  Why does JavaScript do this?

Comment: This is confusing. Maybe a JS "pattern" ? Why would you put the result of the split in the variable itself ? (I mean, in your question here ...)

Comment: What I see is, it first alerts the three array items, then starts alerting each method from the array prototype. Why not use a regular `for` loop (not `for...in`)? See

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `for... in` iterates over all properties of an object (including those from the `prototype`).

When you `for... in` over an array, you get the array elements, as well as the `length` property, and any properties of `Array.prototype`.

You can fix this by using `hasOwnProperty`:

```
for (var i in id){
    if(id.hasOwnProperty(i){
        alert(id[i]);
    }
}​
```

Though, I suggest not using `for... in` for arrays, use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
id.forEach(function(v){
    alert(v);
});
```

Or a good ol' for loop:

```
for(var i=0, len=id.length; i<len; i++){
    alert(id[i]);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

The `forEach` function is not available as a built-in on back-level browsers, so you can do this:

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.forEach !== 'function') {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, thisObj) {
        var scope = thisObj || window,  L = this.length, i;
        for (i=0; i < L; ++i) {
            fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @bfavaretto: `forEach` works in Chrome 7+, Firefox 3.5+, and IE 9+.  http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: forEach may not be supported as a builtin in your browser, but it is easy to define the extension method.

Comment: Yes, I suggest using the new ES5 methods, and just [shimming](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) them into old browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was mistaking it for [`for each...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in), which is non-standard.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I've never seen that before.

Comment: Me neither, until a colleague recently used it and broke our app for most users...

Answer (score 11):

Because the jsFiddle you linked to includes the Mootools library; which adds its own methods to the `Array.prototype`.

When you enumerate over an array using `for in`, it loops over *all* attributes; including those methods; which is what you're seeing.

You should instead check using `hasOwnProperty()`, or, *much preferably* use `for(;;);`

```
for (var i in id){
    if (id.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        alert(id[i]);
    }
}​
```

[(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/DHR8Q/1/)

or

```
for (var i=0;i<id.length;i++) {
    alert(id[i]);
}
```

[(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/DHR8Q/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in JS are objects. When you do a for...in on an array, you get all the indices  as well as all the prototype members of that object.  In your case the prototype members included a bunch of array functions.

You should use a regular for loop to iterate over numeric indices.

This output from the [JSShell](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/jsshell-bundle) in emacs illustrates:

```
js> 
Multi-line input. Use two consecutive blank lines to eval.

var id = "11111;22222;33333"; 

id = id.split(";"); 

js> function say (x) {WScript.echo(x);}
js> for (var i in id) { say (i); } 
0
1
2
forEach
every
map
filter
remove
removeAt
indexOf
contains
js> for(var i=0;i<id.length;i++) { say (i + ": " + id[i]); } 
0: 11111
1: 22222
2: 33333
js>
```

see also: [JavaScript Loops: for...in vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-loops-for-in-vs-for)

Comment: +1 for *not* suggesting that `for-in` + `hasOwnProperty` as a solution.

Comment: yeah, I didn't do it because it feels like the wrong thing to do for an array.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use this for arrays because firstly order is not guaranteed, and secondly these are used to list all enumerable properties of an object which may not be desirable for Arrays as several frameworks add properties to the Array prototype which will also get enumerated.