# Screeps: calculate build cost of body

Tags: javascript, screeps

When playing the game [screeps.com](http://screeps.com/) I want to calculate the cost of building the required body. See my attempt below, where `cfg.body` is the bodypart array, e.g. `[Game.ATTACK, Game.MOVE, Game.WORK, Game.CARRY, Game.MOVE]`:

```
var buildCost = 0;

for(var bodypart in cfg.body){
  switch(bodypart){
    case "MOVE":
    case "CARRY":
       buildCost+=50;
       break;
    case "WORK":
       buildCost+=20;
       break;
    case "HEAL":
       buildCost+=200;
       break;
    case "TOUGH":
       buildCost+=20;
       break;
    case "ATTACK":
       buildCost+=80;
       break;
    case "RANGED_ATTACK":
       buildCost+=150;
       break;
  }
  console.log(bodypart + " costs " + buildCost);
}
```

When printing `bodypart` to the console it shows the indexes (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) and the buildCost remains 0.

The cost and parts are described [on the Screeps page](http://screeps.com/docs/Creep.php).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe the `BODYPART_COST` constant wasn't available before, but with that you can do this:

```
function bodyCost (body) {
    return body.reduce(function (cost, part) {
        return cost + BODYPART_COST[part];
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A more JavaScripty like solution, eliminating the need for a switch, could look like this:

```
var _ = require("lodash");
var body = [Game.WORK, Game.CARRY, Game.MOVE, Game.TOUGH];
var bodyCost = {
  "move": 50,
  "carry": 50,
  "work": 20,
  "heal": 200,
  "tough": 20,
  "attack": 80,
  "ranged_attack": 150
};
var cost = 0;
_.forEach(body, function(part) { cost += bodyCost[part]; });
console.log("Cost of construction: " + cost);
```

In fact, I'm going to use this thing for my own creepfactory to calculate cost. Thanks for figuring out the various costs :)

Comment: Cost changed in game mechanics, updated my answer to reflect the change in costs. Attack went from 100 to 80 [refer to gamedocs](http://screeps.com/docs/Creep.php)

Comment: Updated my sample as well.

Comment: Cost changed in game mechanics, updated my answer to reflect the change in costs. Tough went from 5 to 20 [refer to gamedocs](http://screeps.com/docs/Creep.php).

Comment: The cost has changed again, instead of the object literal you can use the BODYPART_COST constant in the API (it's exactly the same, with current values).

Answer (score 5):

Using lodash's sum method, it's even easier:

```
let cost = _.sum(creep.body.map(function (b) {
               return BODYPART_COST[b];
           }));
```

The arrow method makes it more elegant:

```
let cost = _.sum(creep.body.map((b) => BODYPART_COST[b]));
```

Answer (score 4):

I've updated my solution with using constants as [@Brett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27107925/3163075) does. However I changed the `for in` loop to a `for` loop because of performance as seen in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13646192/3163075)

```
for (var index = 0; index < cfg.body.length; ++index) {
  var bodypart = cfg.body[index];
    switch(bodypart){
      case MOVE:
      case CARRY:
        buildCost += 50;
        break;
      case WORK:
        buildCost += 100;
        break;
      case ATTACK:
        buildCost += 80;
        break;
      case RANGED_ATTACK:
        buildCost += 150;
        break;
      case HEAL:
        buildCost += 250;
        break;
      case TOUGH:
        buildCost += 10;
        break;
      case CLAIM:
        buildCost += 600;
        break;
    }
  console.log(bodypart.toUpperCase()+" costs "+buildCost);
}
```

I also want to note that **you should not use this loop each time you build a creep**, you **better hardcode the value**. However it might be handy in case such value does not exist or you need to double check.

Comment: Why should you not use this loop each time?

Comment: @Robert Because it would cost processor power. A better way to do is to make like a preconfigured setup and calculate the total body cost once and hardcode that value in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you should be comparing the strings in lower case, not upper. Failing that, try using things like Game.MOVE, Game.WORK, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I updated your script to do what you wanted.

The bodypart in for(var bodypart in cfg.body) is only an index

```
var body = [Game.ATTACK,Game.MOVE,Game.WORK,Game.CARRY,Game.MOVE];
var buildCost = 0;
for(var bodypart in body){
    var bodymodule = body[bodypart];
    switch(bodymodule){
        case Game.MOVE:
        case Game.CARRY:
           buildCost+=50;
           break;
        case Game.WORK:
           buildCost+=20;
           break;
        case Game.HEAL:
           buildCost+=200;
           break;
        case Game.TOUGH:
           buildCost+=5;
           break;
        case Game.ATTACK:
           buildCost+=100;
           break;
        case Game.RANGED_ATTACK:
           buildCost+=150;
           break;
    }
}
console.log(body+" costs "+buildCost);
```

Comment: I found the answer myself before you answered, which I now have posted here as well. I used a part of your answer in it and voted you up, however I will accept my answer as I find it more suited. But thanks for your help!