# array push function not working on google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-chrome

I want to fetch multiple checkboxes values from one div. My code executes successfully on firefox but in other browsers it doesn't work. My code looks like

```
var amenity_array = [];
var listofParameters = $("#room-amenity input:checkbox");
for (var index in listofParameters) {
    if ($(listofParameters[index]).attr('checked')) {
        var ste = $(listofParameters[index]).attr('value');
        amenity_array.push(ste);
    }
}
alert(amenity_array);
```

in the above code **amenity_array** alerts within the braces but out of this it doesn't work on chrome.

Comment: Don't use alert. Use `console.log()`

Comment: It also doesn't work. I want to use these amenities in another place.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of suggestions/bugs:

1. Make sure your selector is correct to select checkboxes
2. Use `:checked` to select only the checkboxes that are checked
3. [Don't use `for...in`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645890/javascript-for-in-vs-for-loop-performance) for looping over `array`
4. You can use `each()` to get the `checked` checkboxes and add them in your array
5. Make sure that at-least one checkbox is selected, otherwise the array will have no elements in it

Code:

```
var amenity_array = [];

$('#room-amenity input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    amenity_array.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(amenity_array);
```

Comment: @RAVIPRAKASHAWASTHI You need to open browser console to see result