# The bug in Google Apps Script: sheet.getCharts() and embedded Bubble Chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a Bubble Chart manually on the spreadsheet and I can see it.
But I can't reach it by script. sheet.getCharts() doesn't return my Bubble Chart (but I see other charts)

```
/* OnOpen Trigger modifying an existing (embedded) chart */
function onOpen (e) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var bubbleChart = null;

    var charts = sheet.getCharts();

    debugger

    for (var i in charts) {
      Logger.log(charts[i].getOptions().get('title'));
    }

  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err.toString());
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried logging the length of `charts`? You could also use an explicit loop rather than `for...in` ([here's an explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645890/javascript-for-in-vs-for-loop-performance)).

Comment: I added a screenshot from a debugger. charts[4] [EmbeddedChart, EmbeddedChart, EmbeddedChart, EmbeddedChart] should have 5 EmbeddedCharts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in apps script. It is referenced in a thread dating back to May of this year regarding timeline charts. [I have opened a new bug report with Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69099694).

Comment: Only a question:
A Timeline charts have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, [here's the bug report for timeline charts](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756668)

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view Google doesn't respect Bubble Chart!

**sheet.getCharts()** ignores Bubble Charts!

**EmbeddedBubbleChartBuilder** doesn't exist!
and
**EmbeddedScatterChartBuilder** doesn't care about sizeAxis option.

**ChartType** doesn't contain **BUBBLE** value:
[Enum ChartType | Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-type)