# Create one list from an unknown number of multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My aim is to list all ingredients for a product. Unfortunately there are multiple ingredient arrays, with multiple ingredients inside each array. The amount of arrays will vary product to product so I need someway to capture all ingredients. So far I have:

Finds all ingredient arrays and lists them separately

```
$(function() {
    var params = {
        // Request parameters
        // "gtin": "{string}",
       // "tpnb": "{string}",
       // "tpnc": "{string}",
       // "catid": "{string}",

        // "gtin": "05052004435789",
            "tpnc": "285363525",
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://dev.tescolabs.com/product/?" + $.param(params),
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","key");
        },
        type: "GET",
        // Request body
        data: "{body}",

    })
        .done(function(data) {
            // alert("success");
            // alert(data);
            console.log(data);

var ingredientArrays = data.products[0].ingredients;
var l = ingredientArrays.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++){
   var allIngredients = ingredientArrays[i];
    console.log(allIngredients);
}

        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
});
```

Lists ingredients of a single defined ingredient array, in this case array 2.

```
var list = data.products[0].ingredients[2];
var ingredient = list.split(/[:;,.]+/);
for (list = 0; list < ingredient.length; ++list) {
    console.log(ingredient[list]);
}
```

So far so good, but I wish to merge this functionality so that I can find all ingredients within all arrays and create one single list.

If I do `console.log(data);` I get:

[image]

```
{
  "products": [{
    "gtin": "05054402006097",
    "tpnb": "073706172",
    "tpnc": "285363525",
    "description": "Tesco Stonebaked Thin Double Pepperoni Pizza 330G",
    "brand": "TESCO",
    "qtyContents": {
      "quantity": 330.0,
      "totalQuantity": 330.0,
      "quantityUom": "g",
      "netContents": "330g e"
    },
    "productCharacteristics": {
      "isFood": true,
      "isDrink": false,
      "healthScore": 48,
      "isHazardous": false,
      "storageType": "Frozen"
    },
    "ingredients": [
      "<strong>Wheat</strong> Flour",
      "Tomato Purée",
      "Mozzarella Cheese (<strong>Milk</strong>) (16%), Pepperoni (10%), Water, Mini Pepperoni (3.5%), Yeast, Dextrose, Rapeseed Oil, Salt, Sugar, Dried Garlic, Dried Herbs, Spice. Pepperoni contains: Pork, Pork Fat, Salt, Dextrose, Spices, Spice Extracts, Antioxidants (Extracts of Rosemary, Sodium Ascorbate), Preservative (Sodium Nitrite). Mini Pepperoni contains: Pork, Pork Fat, Salt, Dextrose, Spices, Spice Extracts, Sugar, Antioxidants (Sodium Erythorbate, Extracts of Rosemary), Preservative (Sodium Nitrite)."
    ],
```

UPDATE

To clarify, I can return results in console log like this:

```
tesco.js:70 
["<strong>Wheat</strong> Flour"]
0
:
"<strong>Wheat</strong> Flour"
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
tesco.js:70 
["Tomato Purée"]
0
:
"Tomato Purée"
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
tesco.js:70 
(35) ["Mozzarella Cheese (<strong>Milk</strong>) (16%)", " Pepperoni (10%)", " Water", " Mini Pepperoni (3", "5%)", " Yeast", " Dextrose", " Rapeseed Oil", " Salt", " Sugar", " Dried Garlic", " Dried Herbs", " Spice", " Pepperoni contains", " Pork", " Pork Fat", " Salt", " Dextrose", " Spices", " Spice Extracts", " Antioxidants (Extracts of Rosemary", " Sodium Ascorbate)", " Preservative (Sodium Nitrite)", " Mini Pepperoni contains", " Pork", " Pork Fat", " Salt", " Dextrose", " Spices", " Spice Extracts", " Sugar", " Antioxidants (Sodium Erythorbate", " Extracts of Rosemary)", " Preservative (Sodium Nitrite)", ""]
0
:
"Mozzarella Cheese (<strong>Milk</strong>) (16%)"
1
:
" Pepperoni (10%)"
2
:
" Water"
3
:
" Mini Pepperoni (3"
4
:
"5%)"
5
:
" Yeast"
6
:
" Dextrose"
7
:
" Rapeseed Oil"
8
:
" Salt"
/// and so on\
```

With this code:

```
    var ingredientArrays = data.products[0].ingredients;
    var l = ingredientArrays.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++){
       var allIngredients = ingredientArrays[i];
        var ingredient = allIngredients.split(/[:;,.]+/);
        console.log(ingredient);
    }
```

But as you can see it counts the ingredients separately. I would like them to be one complete list. The count should start at 0 and go up. Instead of displaying the results based on each ingredient array, whereby I get the above result of 1, 1, 35. I would instead get one result of 37.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) i.e: Content of object `data`.

Comment: I have updated my question and added a screen shot which covers this.

Comment: no it does not covers this , you need to click on the link provided to atlest read what it says

Comment: and if possible post the sample array that you are showing in the picture as text inside your post that will provide you more quick responses for the solution

Comment: Ok I have updated again and think I have included all you could need. Sorry I didnt think that it may be necessary to see more than I had initially provided.

Comment: thats ok you will know these things with time, now tell me that the `ingredients`  contents could vary and you want to iterate all of them, is that all?

Comment: that is correct. the number of ingredient arrays in this case is 3 but this is not necessarily going to be the same for every product, and the number of ingredients in total for each of the ingredient arrays will vary also.

Comment: sorry if i am wrong, you mean there could be 2 indexes with the name `ingredients`? I don't think you mean to say that

Comment: no sorry, there will only be one index called `ingredients`. Within that there will be a varying number of arrays. In this case 3 but in other cases maybe more or less. And within each of those there will be varying numbers of ingredients. For example in array 1 in this case there is just 1 (tomato puree) but in array 2 there are lots.

Comment: arrays within `ingredients` i maybe should have said

Comment: added an answer see if that helps

Comment: updated my answer see the **EDIT** section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as your actual problem is that you want to iterate the `response` received from the server and that `response` can have multiple `products` and inside each of those `products` you have `ingredients` array and the size of that array can vary and you want to be able to iterate all the indexes inside it.

You should use `for in` and `for` loop. To see difference see [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645890/javascript-for-in-vs-for-loop-performance).

I will use the provided response data and iterate over it and it will iterate all the `products` and all the `ingredients` inside it.

See a demo below

```js
var response = {
  "products": [{
    "gtin": "05054402006097",
    "tpnb": "073706172",
    "tpnc": "285363525",
    "description": "Tesco Stonebaked Thin Double Pepperoni Pizza 330G",
    "brand": "TESCO",
    "qtyContents": {
      "quantity": 330.0,
      "totalQuantity": 330.0,
      "quantityUom": "g",
      "netContents": "330g e"
    },
    "productCharacteristics": {
      "isFood": true,
      "isDrink": false,
      "healthScore": 48,
      "isHazardous": false,
      "storageType": "Frozen"
    },
    "ingredients": [
      "<strong>Wheat</strong> Flour",
      "Tomato Purée",
      "Mozzarella Cheese (<strong>Milk</strong>) (16%), Pepperoni (10%), Water, Mini Pepperoni (3.5%), Yeast, Dextrose, Rapeseed Oil, Salt, Sugar, Dried Garlic, Dried Herbs, Spice. Pepperoni contains: Pork, Pork Fat, Salt, Dextrose, Spices, Spice Extracts, Antioxidants (Extracts of Rosemary, Sodium Ascorbate), Preservative (Sodium Nitrite). Mini Pepperoni contains: Pork, Pork Fat, Salt, Dextrose, Spices, Spice Extracts, Sugar, Antioxidants (Sodium Erythorbate, Extracts of Rosemary), Preservative (Sodium Nitrite)."
    ],
  }]
}
//console.log(test.products);
let products = response.products;
for (var data in products) {
  let product = products[data];
  let ingredients = product.ingredients;
  console.log("PRODUCT : " + product.brand);
  console.log("=======================");
  console.log("INGREDIENTS");
  for (var i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {

    console.log("--------------" + ingredients[i]);
  }
  console.log("=======================");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

As after your update it is actually that you are splitting each index inside the `ingredients` array on a `regex` i.e `/[:;,.]/` and the resulting indexes of the array can vary and for all those arrays after splitting you want to be merged into a single array so you need to use [**`Array.prototype.concat()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

see a demo below

```js
var test = {
  "products": [{
    "gtin": "05054402006097",
    "tpnb": "073706172",
    "tpnc": "285363525",
    "description": "Tesco Stonebaked Thin Double Pepperoni Pizza 330G",
    "brand": "TESCO",
    "qtyContents": {
      "quantity": 330.0,
      "totalQuantity": 330.0,
      "quantityUom": "g",
      "netContents": "330g e"
    },
    "productCharacteristics": {
      "isFood": true,
      "isDrink": false,
      "healthScore": 48,
      "isHazardous": false,
      "storageType": "Frozen"
    },
    "ingredients": [
      "<strong>Wheat</strong> Flour",
      "Tomato Purée",
      "Mozzarella Cheese (<strong>Milk</strong>) (16%), Pepperoni (10%), Water, Mini Pepperoni (3.5%), Yeast, Dextrose, Rapeseed Oil, Salt, Sugar, Dried Garlic, Dried Herbs, Spice. Pepperoni contains: Pork, Pork Fat, Salt, Dextrose, Spices, Spice Extracts, Antioxidants (Extracts of Rosemary, Sodium Ascorbate), Preservative (Sodium Nitrite). Mini Pepperoni contains: Pork, Pork Fat, Salt, Dextrose, Spices, Spice Extracts, Sugar, Antioxidants (Sodium Erythorbate, Extracts of Rosemary), Preservative (Sodium Nitrite)."
    ],
  }]
}

var ingredientArrays = test.products[0].ingredients;
var l = ingredientArrays.length;
var merged = Array();
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  var allIngredients = ingredientArrays[i];
  var ingredient = allIngredients.split(/[:;,.]+/);
  // merged.push(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], ingredient));
  merged = merged.concat(ingredient);
}

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Thank you @Muhammad Omer Aslam. However my existing code can pretty much do the same thing. I have added further code to my question to evidence where I am at currently and try to explain the better the result I wish to achieve.

Comment: I included the regex stuff in initial question but appreciate I could have explained what result I had and what I wanted a little better. Your EDIT response with the `Array.prototype.concat() ` is exactly the result I was looking for. Thank you for sticking with me :)

Comment: :) thats ok brother you are welcome. @Dan i did noticed the `regex` but didnt knew that you want the splitted arrays to be re-indexed