# return false or true while iterating an array of object

Tags: javascript, if-statement, foreach, return

I would like `find()` function to return `true` when it finds `'john'` and stop iterating trough array.
Or return false if looking for name, let's say `maria`, which is not in any of our objects.
What am I not understanding that I can't achieve what I need in this code?
Thanks.

```
var array = [
    {name:'paul',age:20},
    {name:'john',age:30},
    {name:'albert',age:40}
];

var find = function(arr){
    arr.forEach(function(i){
        if(i.name === 'john'){
            console.log('found him');
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('not there');
            return false;
        }
    });
};
find(array);
```

I have seen some similar questions here but I could not get or understand answer for my question. Explicitly I need the function to be able return the `name` value and at the same time return `true` or `false`.

Comment: btw, you need no semicolon after a block statement `{ /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which stops iterating if a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value is returned inside of the callback.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'paul', age:20 }, { name: 'john', age:30 }, { name: 'albert', age:40 }],
    find = function(array, name) {
        return array.some(function(object) {
            return object.name === name;
        });
    };

console.log(find(array, 'paul'));  // true
console.log(find(array, 'maria')); // false
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is exactly what I was looking for. works perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning in the `forEach(function(i) {})`, which is only returning in the inside function `function(i) {}`, that does not help return from the outer function `find()`. Also, your logic with `return false;` seems also problematic. Simply use normal `for` loops would be fine.

```js
var array = [
    {name:'paul',age:20},
    {name:'john',age:30},
    {name:'albert',age:40}
];

var find = function(arr, name) {
  for (let i of arr) {
    if(i.name === name){
      console.log('found ' + name);
      return true;
    }
  }
  console.log(name + ' not there');
  return false;
};

find(array, 'paul');
find(array, 'maria');
```

Comment: Using the `for..of` loop with arrays isn't ideal performance-wise. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645890/javascript-for-in-vs-for-loop-performance

Comment: @bukharim96 Yeah I did not intend to make it of high performance, simply trying to point out the problem of the original code block

Answer (score 0):

Stop using the `forEach` method and try this instead:

```js
var array = [
    {name:'paul',age:20},
    {name:'john',age:30},
    {name:'albert',age:40}
];

var find = function(arr){
 var returnValue = false;
    
    for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i].name === 'john') {
       ret = true;
       break;
      }
    }

    return returnValue;
};
find(array);
```