# Is there a better way, to iterate through

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to iterate in a better way through A and B?

Data structure A:

`AbsatzNrSaetzeText: { [key: string]: string[]` };

Data structure B:

```
 AbsatzNrSaetzeText: Record<number, string[]>;
```

Is there a better way, to get that value:

```
     for (var i = 0; i < this.UI_Seiten.length; i++) {
      for (var j in this.UI_Seiten[i].AbsatzNrSaetzeText) {
        for (var k = 0; k < this.UI_Seiten[i].AbsatzNrSaetzeText[j.valueOf()].length; k++) {
          console.log(this.UI_Seiten[i].AbsatzNrSaetzeText[j.valueOf()][k]);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13646192/1627271).

Comment: `j` is a string. Why do you call `.valueOf()` on that? o.O

Comment: @AluanHaddad `Array.prototype.flatMap()`

Comment: @Andreas good catch! It needs to be `this.UI_Seiten.flatMap(Object.values).flat()` or `this.UI_Seiten.map(Object.values).flat(2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iterable objects (like arrays), there is no need to reference the index in order to iterate over the values - `for..of` allows for significantly cleaner code, by putting the value being iterated over directly into an identifier that can be used in later loops.

Use `Object.values` instead of `for..in`, since you don't care about the key on the object, only about the value.

```
for (const seiten of this.UI_Seiten) {
    for (const arr of Object.values(seiten.AbsatzNrSaetzeText)) {
        for (const str of arr) {
            console.log(str);
        }
    }
}
```