# Iterating over an array with "holes" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, iteration

I have got an array from which some items are going to be removed; but some loops are still running on them, so I want to simply skip the places where I remove my objects

I know that the syntax for(i in array) should do this because it iterates on the index, but how should I remove my items then ? Because when i do array[4] = null, my for just doesn't care and goes on trying to use the value at 4.

I also tried to check if !null but without success...
thank you

Comment: `for in`'s are for enumerating object properties. You should be using a standard `for` loop for iterating over an array. For more info see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-loops-for-in-vs-for

Comment: If you *really* need to iterate over a sparse array, use `for(i in array) { if(!isNaN(+i)) ... }`. (Bonus tip: you probably don't need to iterate over a sparse array. This is only for cases in which you have a array with *hugely* distant indices, e.g. `5` and `10000000` are the only populated indices.)

Comment: Delete the array element properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove an item without leaving a hole, you should use `.splice()`

```
myarray.splice(idx, 1);
```

---

But if you're saying that you *want* the holes there, but want to skip them, then you can use `delete` to remove the item *(leaving a hole)*, and use `.forEach()` for the iteration, which skips holes.

```
delete myarray[idx];

// ...

myarray.forEach(function(item, i) {
    // holes will be skipped
});
```

To support older browsers like IE8 and lower, you'll need to add a compatibility patch for `forEach()`.

- [MDN `.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) *(Ignore the shorter patch. It's a poor non-compliant version.)*

Comment: i can use splice but is it memory hungry ? cause it is in an infinite loop (i am doing a game)

Comment: @user1397271: It will reindex the Array from the spliced point forward, so it takes some processing.