# Using the delete operator

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the `delete` unary operator talked about near bottom of page here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Unary)

It says deleting an item from an array will make the item `undefined`. However, as the code below shows, we cannot loop over this `undefined` item like we can do with a fresh array with the explicit value of `undefined` as one of its items.

Is this just a quirk or is there more to read into here? It doesn't seem meaningful to describe the deleted item as `undefined` when it's not treated like `undefined`.

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];

console.log("untampered-with array:", a);

delete a[0];

console.log("array after first item deleted:", a);

a.forEach(element => {
    console.log("looping over each item and printing it:", element);
});

b = [undefined, 1, 2];

b.forEach(element => {
    console.log("looping over each item of array with undefined explicitly declared:", element);
});
```

It might also be worth mentioning that in Visual Studio Code, when we print out `a` after the first item is deleted, it does not show the first item as undefined (like it does on the Stack Overflow code simulator). It shows this:
[image]

Comment: is there a question in here?

Comment: It creates a *hole* in the array. `forEach` and other arrray  methods skip over the holes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13847793/3082296

Comment: "*`trees[3]` is removed with delete. However, `trees[3]` is still addressable and returns undefined*" - that's not expressed very well. *Any* property is addressable in javascript regardless whether it exists or not, and returns `undefined` when it doesn't exist, there's nothing special about arrays here.

Comment: [Do not use `delete` on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500606/1048572). Never. I'll update MDN to include a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use splice method to remove array items instead of using delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use **splice**

`let b = a.splice(0, 1)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/splice

or **filter**

`let b = a.filter((item, i) => { return i !== 0 })`

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter

In both case, `b` is a new array without the item indexed at 0.