# Retrieving links from webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I'm new to javascript and simply trying to pull links from a webpage so I'm doing the following:

```
for(link in document.links) { 
   console.log(link.getAttribute("href");
}
```

But if I do this:

```
document.links.item(0).getAttribute("href")
```

It returns the link for the first `href`

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the webpage I'm testing against: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get the elements by tag name and [avoid the `for in` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-loops-for-in-vs-for).

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    i;

for(i = 0; i < links.length; i += 1){
    console.log(links[i].getAttribute("href"));
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j098kmnp/)

---

For your example, you would have used:

```
for(link in document.links) { 
   console.log(document.links[link].getAttribute("href"));
}
```

While that technically works, it returns prototype properties in addition to the link elements. This will throw errors since `.getAttribute("href")` won't work for all the return elements.

You could use the [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method and check.. but still, i'd [avoid the `for in` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-loops-for-in-vs-for).

```
for (link in document.links) {
    if (document.links.hasOwnProperty(link)) {
        console.log(document.links[link]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer was also very helpful to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.links.item
```

is an array of items.

document.links.item(0) gets the first item in that array.

document.links.item(1) gets the second item in that array.

To answer your question, what you are doing wrong is that you are not looping the links.item array as you did in your first example.

Comment: So document.links is not iteratively returning each link in document.links?

Comment: No. Only for loops do iterate. document.links.item does, however, give you the whole collection of items at once. But document.links.item.getAttribute("href") will be undefined, because getAttribute() is not a function of the array.

Comment: I see and that makes sense now.  document.links was not returning a link object, so there is no getAttribute() function available.  So I need to return the document.links.items to get each link object.

Comment: @inquisitor Correct. Just as you did at first. I'd like to suggest Josh's answer, though :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are accessing item 0 and only getting the href from that. For that reason, you will only get one link.

What you probably want to do is get the href for all of the of the links at once

```
var hrefs = [], i
for (i=0;i<document.links.length;++i) {
    hrefs.push(document.links.item(i).getAttribute('href'))
}
```

Then your hrefs array will contains all the urls