# Explaination needed: Different outputs when used for...in and for(;;) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, for-in-loop

In NodeJS, I created the following two scripts, both of them was intended to remove even numbers from an array.

This is my 1st script:

```
#!/usr/bin/nodejs
var myarr = [2,3,5,1,6,2,28,5,7,90,3];
console.log(myarr);
for(var i in myarr){
        if(myarr[i] % 2 == 0){
                myarr.splice(i,1);
                --i;
        }
}
console.log(myarr);
```

Output for the first script was following:

```
[ 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 2, 28, 5, 7, 90, 3 ]
[ 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 7, 3 ]
```

In 2nd script, I changed `for..in` loop to `for(;;)` loop as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/nodejs
var myarr = [2,3,5,1,6,2,28,5,7,90,3];
console.log(myarr);
for(var i=0;i<myarr.length;i++){
        if(myarr[i] % 2 == 0){
                myarr.splice(i,1);
                --i;
        }
}
console.log(myarr);
```

I got following output for the 2nd script:

```
[ 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 2, 28, 5, 7, 90, 3 ]
[ 3, 5, 1, 5, 7, 3 ]
```

Although my intention was the same, two for loops gave me different outputs. I figured out that, in my first script, if there are two adjacent even numbers exist in the original array, `if` condition seems to be applied for the first even number only where the second even number is skipped. I would really appreciate if anybody can explain this difference clearly.

Comment: Don't use `for...in` to iterate over an array (or a collection in general).

Comment: iterating and removing at the same time is not a good idea.

Comment: And to better get an idea what is happening, put this `console.log('i = ' , i, ' myarr = ', myarr);` after this `for(var i in myarr){` .

Comment: http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4: "*A property name must not be visited more than once in any enumeration.*". Your `--i` in the `for in`-loop is futile (you could use a `while` instead of the `if` however).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is wrong. You're removing keys from the array whilst looping through the same array. Your `for...in` loop will only ever perform 7 iterations, as 4 of your keys are spliced from the array whilst the array is still being iterated through, whereas your `for(;;)` loop will always perform all 11 iterations as this is defined at the beginning (`myarr.length`).

You should define a second array to use for your results instead:

**for...in**

```
var myarr = [2,3,5,1,6,2,28,5,7,90,3],
    resultarr = [];
console.log(myarr);
for(var i in myarr){
    if(myarr[i] % 2 != 0){
        resultarr.push(myarr[i])
    }
}
console.log(resultarr);
```

```js
-> [3, 5, 1, 5, 7, 3]
```

**for(;;)**

```
var myarr = [2,3,5,1,6,2,28,5,7,90,3],
    resultarr = [];
console.log(myarr);
for(var i=0;i<myarr.length;i++){
    if(myarr[i] % 2 != 0){
        resultarr.push(myarr[i]);
    }
}
console.log(resultarr);
```

```js
-> [3, 5, 1, 5, 7, 3]
```

---

As an ending note, you shouldn't use the `for...in` loop for iterating through arrays anyway. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263872/1317805) details why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explaination. I knew I could use a second array to push odd numbers. But I wanted to do it without using any additional arrays.