# weird "addEventListener is not a function" exception

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, event-listener

the code below cannot run properly on Google Chrome :

```
var e,
    divStyle = {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.29)",
        postion: "fixed",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%"
    },
    imgStyle = {
        maxWidth: "700px",
        maxHeight: "700px"
    },
    imgDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("resumeAttchImg"),
    listener = function () {
        var style,
            img = this.firstElementChild;
        for (style in divStyle)
            this.style[style] = divStyle[style];
        for (style in imgStyle)
            img.style[style] = imgStyle[style];
    };
for (e in imgDivs) {
    imgDivs[e].addEventListener("click", listener);
    console.log(imgDivs[e].addEventListener);
}
```

Chrome threw an exception:

> "Uncaught TypeError: imgDivs[e].addEventListener is not a function"

how ever, `console.log(imgDivs[e].addEventListener)` do print a function definition like :

> function test.html:182 addEventListener() { [native code] }

how to fix this?

Comment: Use a normal `for` loop, not a `for...in` loop to iterate over a `NodeList`.

Comment: why are you using a `for in` loop? use either a regular loop, native forEach, or reverse while.

Comment: To add to @FelixKling's comment, consider reading [this StackOverflow post about `for..in vs for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-loops-for-in-vs-for)

Comment: Just to know, why does it respond only on for loop? Because on a lesson I sow online, they did it without it - like this:       var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";

});

Comment: @NadavHimmelfarb I was trying to apply the same styles to a list of elements instead of single one, so the `for` loop helps to keep the code clean. However, the `for in` loop iterates all elements in the return value of `getElementsByClassName` which is a `NodeList` type containing extra properties than simply node elements.