# invoque array in object JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have invoque array Object in Object JSON but I invoque last index

```js
var myObj, x, i, y;
myObj = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "cars": [{
    "n": "Ford",
    "a": "BMW",
    "c": "Fiat"
  }, {
    "n": "test",
    "a": "BMWwww",
    "c": "Fiattt"
  }]
};
x = myObj.cars[0]["n"];
for (y in myObj.cars) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.cars[y].n;

}
```

```html
<p>Access an array value of a JSON object:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

but I have display

> Access an array value of a JSON object:
>          test

Comment: What you want to show?

Comment: Technical note: You have  JavaScript object.  JSON is used when you serialize and deserialize objects.  JSON syntax looks a lot like JavaScript Object Notation.  (Look at the capital letters.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `innerHTML`. You could add the value and a line break tag.

Then I suggest to use a simple `for` loop with an index variable to use. You might habe a looke here: [JavaScript Loops: for…in vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-loops-for-in-vs-for)

```js
var myObj = { name: "John", age: 30, cars: [{ n: "Ford", a: "BMW", c: "Fiat" }, { n: "test", a: "BMWwww", c: "Fiattt" }] },
    i;

for (i = 0; i < myObj.cars.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj.cars[i].n + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<p>Access an array value of a JSON object:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```