# Difference between normal for loop and for...in?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, properties

I'm trying to write a function to fulfil the following requirements:

Given an object and a key, "getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty" returns an array containing all the elements of the array located at the given key that are equal to ten.

Notes:

- If the array is empty, it should return an empty array.
- If the array contains no elements are equal to 10, it should return
  an empty array.
- If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return an
  empty array.
- If there is no property at the key, it should return an empty array.

Example:

```
var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};
var output = getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key');
console.log(output); // --> [10, 10]
```

Approach #1 (fails the final point *If there is no property at the key, it should return an empty array.):

```
function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {

  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
    if (obj[key][i] === 10) {
      output.push(obj[key][i]);
    }
  }
 return output;
}
```

Approach #2 passes all:

```
function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {

  var output = [];
  for (let i in obj[key]) {
    if (obj[key][i] === 10) {
      output.push(obj[key][i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

From my understanding, both loops and the subsequent conditional push has the same logic. Why does one work over the other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-loops-for-in-vs-for

Answer (score 1):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. I would just do this:

```
function getSameVals(yourArray, val){
  var a = [];
  for(var i=0,l=yourArray.length; i<l; i++){
    if(yourArray[i] === val){
      a.push(val);
    }
  }
  return a;
}
var ten = getSameVals(obj.key, 10);
console.log(ten);
```