# Uncaught TypeError: items is not iterable

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, for-in-loop

My understanding is that `for...in` loops are designed to iterate over objects in Javascript. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263847/javascript-loops-for-in-vs-for) and [this post.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Take the following example. This returns 'Uncaught TypeError: items is not iterable' in my console.

```js
var text = {
  name: "Coptic",
  ranges: [[994, 1008], [11392, 11508], [11513, 11520]],
  direction: "ltr",
  year: -200,
  living: false,
  link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_alphabet"
};

function dominantDirection(items) {
  for (let item of items) {
    if (item.direction === 'ltr') {
      return 'ltr';
    } else {
      return 'rtl';
    }
  }
}

console.log(dominantDirection(text));
```

If I wrap the object in an array[] it works fine.
However my second example works as expected.

```js
var object1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var string1 = "";

function loopObj() {
  for (var property1 in object1) {
    console.log(string1 = string1 + object1[property1]);
  }
}

console.log(loopObj());
```

Why does the first example require an array and the second does not?

Comment: `text` is not an array for example!

Comment: Your first code sample uses `for ... of` not `for ... in`.

Comment: Both snippets are doing something completely different. The first is looping over a collection of objects and returning immediately after checking the direction of the first object in the collection. The second snippet is iterating over every property of the passed in object.

Comment: In your first example, you don't have to iterate through the `text` object to retrieve the direction (you are basically doing two levels of iteration). Simply access the direction via `items.direction` is sufficient.

Comment: @Pointy wow, I feel silly. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your first example you used `for..of` which cannot be used on objects but on strings and arrays. To iterate an object either use `for..in` construct or you get the keys of the object into an array by using `Object.keys()`.

Example using `Object.keys()`:

```js
const text = {
  name: "Coptic",
  ranges: [[994, 1008], [11392, 11508], [11513, 11520]],
  direction: "ltr",
  year: -200,
  living: false,
  link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_alphabet"
};

for (let key of Object.keys(text)) {
  
  console.log(`${key}: ${text[key]}`);
}
```

Or you could also use the new `Object.entries()` to get the key and value like below:

```js
const text = {
  name: "Coptic",
  ranges: [[994, 1008], [11392, 11508], [11513, 11520]],
  direction: "ltr",
  year: -200,
  living: false,
  link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_alphabet"
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(text)) {
  
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```