# (node:28917) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: data is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch API using [vessel finder API](https://api.vesselfinder.com/docs/vesselslist.html). After obtaining a fixed and predefined list of vessels I decided from the API, I would like to inject them in a table. 
However as soon as I launch the application I receive an error `(node:28917) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: data is not iterable`. I have no idea why that is happening.
I am launching separately an application that fetched the API, and another application which is the interface side.

Below the typical API response of their API:

```
[  
    {  
        "AIS":{  
            "MMSI":227441980,
            "TIMESTAMP":"2017-08-11 11:17:37 UTC",
            "LATITUDE":46.1459,
            "LONGITUDE":-1.16631,
            "COURSE":360.0,
            "SPEED":0.0,
            "HEADING":511,
            "NAVSTAT":1,            
            "IMO":0,
            "NAME":"CLEMENTINE",
            "CALLSIGN":"FJVK",
            "TYPE":60,
            "A":0,
            "B":0,
            "C":0,
            "D":0,
            "DRAUGHT":0.0,
            "DESTINATION":"",
            "ETA_AIS":"00-00 00:00",
            "ETA":"",
            "SRC":"TER",
            "ZONE": "North Sea",
            "ECA": true      
        }
    }
]
```

Below the code I am using to launch the API request on a terminal: `npm start`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var axios = require('axios');
const NodeCache = require('node-cache');
const myCache = new NodeCache();

let hitCount = 0;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/hello', async function(req, res, next) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        'https://api.vesselfinder.com/vesselslist?userkey=KEY'
    );
    const [ metaData, ships ] = data;
    res.send(data);
    return;
});

module.exports = router;
```

Below the second application I launch in another terminal: `npm start`

**ShipTracker.js**

```
const shipCompanyMap = {
    MICHIGAN: 'DONJON',
    MAGDALEN: 'WEEKS',
    MURDEN: 'USACE'
};

const Ship = ({ ship, logoMap, logoClick }) => {
    const shipName = ship.AIS.NAME;
    const company = shipCompanyMap[shipName];
    const img = logoMap[company];
    return (
        <div onClick={(event) => logoClick(event, ship)}>
            {/* Render shipImage image */}
            <img src={img} alt="Logo" />
        </div>
    );
};
export { Ship };

const ShipTracker = ({ ships, setActiveShip }) => {
    console.log('These are the ships: ', { ships });

    return (
        <div className="ship-tracker">
            <Table className="flags-table" responsive hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>MMSI</th>
                        <th>TIMESTAMP</th>
                        <th>LATITUDE</th>
                        <th>LONGITUDE</th>
                        <th>COURSE</th>
                        <th>SPEED</th>
                        <th>HEADING</th>
                        <th>NAVSTAT</th>
                        <th>IMO</th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>CALLSIGN</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {ships.map((ship, index) => {
                        const cells = [
                            ship.AIS.MMSI,
                            ship.AIS.TIMESTAMP,
                            ship.AIS.LATITUDE,
                            ship.AIS.LONGITUDE,
                            ship.AIS.COURSE,
                            ship.AIS.SPEED,
                            ship.AIS.HEADING,
                            ship.AIS.NAVSTAT,
                            ship.AIS.IMO,
                            ship.AIS.NAME,
                            ship.AIS.CALLSIGN
                        ];

                        return (
                            <tr
                                onClick={() => setActiveShip(ship.AIS.NAME, ship.AIS.LATITUDE, ship.AIS.LONGITUDE)}
                                key={index}
                            >
                                <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                                {cells.map((cell) => <td key={ship.AIS.MMSI}>{cell}</td>)}
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ShipTracker;
```

**GoogleMap.js**

```
import { Ship } from '../components/ShipTracker';


handleMarkerClick = (event, data) => {
    this.props.setActiveShip(data.AIS.NAME, data.AIS.LATITUDE, data.AIS.LONGITUDE);
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="google-map">
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'KEY' }}
                center={{
                    lat: this.props.activeShip ? this.props.activeShip.latitude : 37.99,
                    lng: this.props.activeShip ? this.props.activeShip.longitude : -97.31
                }}
                zoom={5.5}
            >

                {/* Rendering all the markers here */}
                {this.state.ships.map((ship) => (
                    <Ship
                        ship={ship}
                        key={ship.AIS.MMSI}
                        lat={ship.AIS.LATITUDE}
                        lng={ship.AIS.LONGITUDE}
                        logoMap={this.state.logoMap}
                        logoClick={this.handleMarkerClick}
                    />
                ))}
            </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
}
}



export default class GoogleMap extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ships: [],
        activeShipTypes: [],
        activeCompanies: [],
        activeShip: null
    };
async componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3001/hello';
    console.log(url);
    const fetchingData = await fetch(url);
    const ships = await fetchingData.json();

    console.log(ships);

    this.setState({
        ships
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <MapContainer>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.activeShip, null, 2)}</pre>

            <BoatMap
                setActiveShip={this.setActiveShip}
                activeShip={this.state.activeShip}
            />
            <ShipTracker
                ships={this.state.ships}
                setActiveShip={this.setActiveShip}
                onMarkerClick={this.handleMarkerClick}
            />
        </MapContainer>
    );
}
```

}

Posts I used but that did not help me figure out the problem are: [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/is_not_iterable),

[I also used this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9210) and [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389545/uncaught-typeerror-items-is-not-iterable).

Please advice on how to move on as I am running out of ideas and don't know how to move on anymore.

Comment: `const [ metaData, ships ] = data;` where does `data` come from?

Comment: @BrianThompson, thanks for reading the question. Sorry it was a copy/paste problem, there was a missin line. The code is updated, thanks for catching that, but that was not the problem. Only a silly mistake from my side. :)

Comment: What do you get if you console log `data`?

Comment: I get almost all the sips that I am looking for. The problem is that the array in the `ShipTracker.js` seems to be [empty](https://i.imgur.com/PomAVsj.png) and I don't know why because the answer from the fetch seems to be correct.

Comment: Basically from `ShipTracker.js` this gives an empty array `console.log('These are the ships: ', { ships });`

Comment: [This is also from the terminal](https://i.imgur.com/wepvXYG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the problem in this line, the error helps you a lot to realise that this is wrong:

```
 const [ metaData, ships ] = data;
```

You get that `data` is not iterable. That means `data` is not an array as you expect when trying to destructure it to get the inner values. In your case probably its value is `undefined` and when trying to destructure it you get the `TypeError: data is not iterable` error that then throws the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` because you are not surrounding your call in a `try / catch` scope. So you need to review carefully the call you are making in:

```
const { data } = await axios.get('https://api.vesselfinder.com/vesselslist?userkey=KEY');
```

I recommend you to start debugging it by instead destructuring to retrieve the data, to save the whole response and by debugging (or using `console.log`) to see if you are getting a valid response and also surround the code of your endpoint like this:

```
router.get('/hello', async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://api.vesselfinder.com/vesselslist?userkey=KEY');
    const [ metaData, ships ] = data;
    res.send(data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error); // You will later would need to manage the error sent where you make the API call from your React code.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reading the question. I have to go catch the bus now, as soon as I get home I will get back you!

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution and it compiles. However it triggered another error. If you have time I posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636903/reactjs-how-to-fix-typeerror-data-is-not-iterable) with the [small problem](https://i.imgur.com/Q8fzDqf.png) I have. Thank you for your time yesterday! :)