# ReactJS: How to fix TypeError: data is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two applications running at the same time. The first one is fetching APIs from [vessel-finder](https://api.vesselfinder.com/docs/vesselslist.html) and finding only a specific number of boats.
The second application is the user interface used to visualize data from the fetch, specifically latitude and longitude of boats.

**The problem** I have is that the fetch seems to arrive correctly to the end point but that throws an error of `TypeError: data is not iterable` as also shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW46e.png) on the terminal.

It seems that the problem might be the API fetch. Below the code I am using for that:

```
router.get('/hello', async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
            'https://api.vesselfinder.com/vesselslist?userkey=KEY'
        );
        const [ metaData, ships ] = data;
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error);
        console.log(error);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

While investigating what the problem might be, I came across [this source](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/typeerror-map-is-not-a-function/346460) which also uses `axios` to get the call to the API.
I wonder now if the fetch I am making is basically incomplete and because of that, `data is not iterable`...
Also from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626008/node28917-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-typeerror-data-is-not-iterable) I was able to handle a missing `Promise` using a `try-catch` block that was preventing me from compiling.

Is the problem due to a missing `axios.get('API call').then.setState` instruction I am missing?, if so how could I fix that?

Thank you very much for pointing to the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: It simply indicates that the data returned by the endpoint is not a list or a list-like object so you can't do `const [metaData, ships] = data` on it. Open the network tab of your developer toolbar and inspect the response of your endpoint. It is probably not a list.

Comment: Thanks for reading the question. [this is the Network tab](https://i.imgur.com/bkDCIY0.png) response. What should I look for?

Comment: Can you try to print the content of `data` to the console? What does it show? I probably is not what you think.

Comment: Ok I just `console.log(data + 'This is the error')` and [this](https://i.imgur.com/cHMO7jY.png) is the result of the terminal. Is that telling you something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look out for this line in your code -

```
 const [ metaData, ships ] = data;
```

perform object destructuring either between two objects or between two arrays. You are trying it out between an array and an object, which is a flaw.
For more details, check https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring